# Using lambda for builder pattern

Tags: c#, lambda, telerik, builder

The telerik grid uses lambda syntax to enhance the builder patter when binding to columns.

```
.Columns(cols =>
    {
        cols.Bound(e => e.Tag);
        cols.Bound(e => e.Name);
     });
```

I would like to make a similar function in my code. I already have the syntax for the Bound() function down.  But what would the syntax for the Columns() function look like?

Here is a better example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
class SubList
{
    private List<string> _items;

    public AddItem(string item)
    {
        _items.Add(item);
    }
}

class MyCollections
{
    private Dictionary<string, SubList> _subs = new Dictionary<string,SublList>();

    public SubList AddList(string name)
    {
        var newSub = new SubList();
        _subs[name] = newSub;
        return newSub;
    }
}

class Other
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        var collections = new MyCollections();

        //if add item throws error, I don't know which one it is as.
        //it is also hard to put a break point in here.
        collections.AddList("one")
            .AddItem("1")
            .AddItem("un")
            .AddItem("uno");

        //I would like to have something like this:
        collections.AddList("two") { s =>
            s.AddItem("1");
            s.AddItem("un"); //yay! can put breakpoint here
            s.AddItem("uno");
        };

        //or perhaps
        collections.AddList("two").Sub( s => {
            s.AddItem("1");
            s.AddItem("un"); //yay! can put breakpoint here
            s.AddItem("uno");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It could either be an extension method or an instance method, probably on the order of:

```
// Assuming some grid type TDataGrid and some column building type TColumnBuilder
public TDataGrid Columns(Action<TColumnBuilder> applyColumns)
{
    // Ask the user what they'd like to do with our columns
    TColumnBuilder placeholder = new TColumnBuilder();
    applyColumns(placeholder);

    // do something with what we've learned
    // this.columns = placeholder.CreateColumns();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this might be it, let me test.

Comment: So in my example above, I'd need to implement the 'Sub()' method in SubList similar to your Columns method?